# extendTraces using timestamps as x-value

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

The [code snippet](https://codepen.io/fera0013/pen/mdQzyLE)

```html
<p class="codepen" data-height="300" data-default-tab="html,result" data-slug-hash="mdQzyLE" data-user="fera0013" style="height: 300px; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; border: 2px solid; margin: 1em 0; padding: 1em;">
  <span>See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/fera0013/pen/mdQzyLE">
  extend multiple traces at once</a> by fera0013 (<a href="https://codepen.io/fera0013">@fera0013</a>)
  on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</span>
</p>
<script async src="https://cpwebassets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```

creates a plotly plot with two traces, using

```
Plotly.newPlot('graph', [{
  y: [],
  mode: 'lines+markers', 
  marker: {color: 'pink', size: 8},
  line: {width: 4}
}, {
  y: [],
  mode: 'lines+markers',
  marker: {color: 'gray', size:8},
  line: {width: 4}
}]);
```

that are extended by random number at regular intervals, using

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  Plotly.extendTraces('graph', {
    y: [[rand()], [rand()]],
    //x: [[Date.now()],[Date.now()]]
  }, [0, 1])

  cnt = cnt+1;
  if(cnt === 100) clearInterval(interval);
}, 500);
```

What modifications are necessary to use the current timestamp as x values, for each trace extension?

The outcommented line in

```
Plotly.extendTraces('graph', {
        y: [[rand()], [rand()]],
        //x: [[Date.now()],[Date.now()]]
      }, [0, 1])
```

did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the x-axis are initialised like

```
Plotly.newPlot('graph', [{
  x: [Date.now()],
  y: [],
  mode: 'lines+markers', 
  marker: {color: 'pink', size: 8},
  line: {width: 4}
}, {
  x: [Date.now()],
  y: [],
  mode: 'lines+markers',
  marker: {color: 'gray', size:8},
  line: {width: 4}
}]);
```

The function

```
  Plotly.extendTraces('graph', {
    y: [[rand()], [rand()]],
    x: [[Date.now()],[Date.now()]]
```

seems to work as intended:

```html
<p class="codepen" data-height="300" data-default-tab="html,result" data-slug-hash="mdQzyLE" data-user="fera0013" style="height: 300px; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; border: 2px solid; margin: 1em 0; padding: 1em;">
  <span>See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/fera0013/pen/mdQzyLE">
  extend multiple traces at once</a> by fera0013 (<a href="https://codepen.io/fera0013">@fera0013</a>)
  on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</span>
</p>
<script async src="https://cpwebassets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```